# Onchange dropdown values query resp. tables - with php , mysql , ajax , jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**Main Drop-down :**

```
<select name="sometest">
  <option value="1"> A </option>
  <option value="2"> B </option>
  <option value="3"> C </option>
  <option value="4"> D </option>
  <option value="5"> E </option>
</select>
```

Now here When value 1 , 2, 3 , 4  is on-change it should get its details from table_1 and when Value 5 is on-change then its details come from another table_2 with field( name , size , title)  .

Kindly note both table_1 and table_2 have same coloumn field name.

now after onchange of resp. value i get  another drop-down listing with resp. table query.

Suppose when i on-change for 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 value , then it query table_1 with field name, size, title and list it under resp drop-down sections.

**Drop-down list : on-change value for 1,2,3,4 from table_1**

Here : coloumn "name" all value  is listed under name , coloumn "size" all value is listed under size and coloumn "title" all value is listed under title from **table_1**

```
<select name="name">
  <option value="n1"> Apple </option>
  <option value="n2"> Boy </option>
  <option value="n3"> Cat </option>
</select>

<select name="size">
  <option value="12"> 0-1 </option>
  <option value="21"> 1-1 </option>
</select>


<select name="title">
  <option value="1"> whatever </option>
  <option value="2"> same whatever </option>
</select>
```

similarly when **Value 5** is select from Main Drop-down , then it query all column field from **table_2** and list it under resp. drop-down

Comment: r u using ajax for get result?

Comment: i am newbie , so no idea about it .. hence asking for help :(

Comment: Did you try any code ?

Comment: @ Mahmood , as said i am newbie in jquery , ajax .. but yes i tried my hand on studying jquery and ajax , and after some research i got to know that Onchange of jquery with ajax in loop may help me on this .. but confuse to start from where , as from Main dropdown i have to query 2 table as per its value

Answer (score 1):

user ajax onchange select box pass the value of select

HTML

```
 <select name="sometest" onchange="javascript:call_ajax_fun(this.value);">
      <option value="1"> A </option>
      <option value="2"> B </option>
      <option value="3"> C </option>
      <option value="4"> D </option>
      <option value="5"> E </option>
    </select>
```

JS Ajax Function

```
function call_ajax_fun(str)
{

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {

            var result = xmlhttp.responseText;
            if(xmlhttp.responseText!='')
            {
                document.getElementById('your_result_div_id').innerHTML =result ;
                            // put your result in your div 
            }   
        }
    }



    var url="get_result.php?pas_val="str;

    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);

    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

and your get result file will be as follows

**get_result.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['pas_val']))
{
   $pas_val = $_REQUEST['pas_val'];
   if($pas_val<5)
   {
     $tbl = "table_1";
   }
   else
  {
     $tbl = "table_2";
  }


// your table is in $tbl variable
//   your your table here in your code


}
else
{
  exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: @ Satish thanks for reply , but what about listing of my other dropdowns values from resp. tables as per column fields

Comment: @user2906577 use $pas_val in if-else on get_result.php and define your table as i edited the answer.